# MVC2 .NET - Paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok I know there is some code out there for pagination in MVC but it seems to be for version 1, Scott mentioned that he was goint to implement to code into the release of version 2.

Was this code included? If so whats the best way to achieve pagination in MVC2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to do this the old fashioned way and it works.

---

Yikes this is an old question and a poor answer by me. This was asked around the time of MVC beta. There is plenty of stuff on the web that will now advise on Pagination;

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/amit12345/pagination-in-mvc-application/

Answer (score 2):

You can lool at [mvc contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib). It contains grid control and pager.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it without anything 'on top' of MVC.